# How to update a class with an observable in Angular2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

My problem is simple. I have a study class. And I want (when I click on a button) change this class to another study. So I create an observable which give me the class (throught a .json). But when I subscribe to this observable, throught my function 'getStudy' my class study changed but and won't show up with {{study.name}}.

My studies.component

```
import {StudiesListService} from '../_services/studieslist.service';
import {studiesList} from '../_models/studiesList';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {Study} from '../_models/study';
import {StudyProvider} from '../_services/studyprovider.service';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'studiescomponent',
  templateUrl: 'studies.component.html',
})


export class StudiesComponent {
  studyName : string = "test"
  public study : Study = { name: 'test'} ;
  studieslist : studiesList;

  constructor(private _studiesListService : StudiesListService,
              private _studyProvider : StudyProvider ){
  }

 ngOnInit(){
    this._studiesListService.getStudiesListfromAPI()
                            .subscribe( res => this.studieslist =res,
                                        err => console.error(err.status)
     );
}

getStudy(studyName : string){
    this._studyProvider.getStudyfromAPI(studyName)
     .subscribe( res => this.study=res,
                 err => console.error(err.status));

  }
}
```

Note that StudiesListService provide me the list of the studies.

And here is my studyProvider.service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {Study} from '../_models/study'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'
@Injectable()

export class StudyProvider{
  public data : Object;
  constructor(private _http:Http){

 }
  getStudyfromAPI(studyname : string){
    var path : string = '../CDN/';
    path = path.concat(studyname);
    path = path.concat('.json');
    return this._http.get(path)
      .do( x => console.log(x))
      .map( res =>res.json())
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting the list of studies in the ngOnInit method? Then going back in the getStudy method to just get one study? Why not just pull it from the list you already have?

Comment: Because it's a test for the moment, the study class will have a lot of properties, and I don't want to load all those properties of all studies ( they will also be a lot of studies). So i load the list, and when the user click on the list it shows the selected study @DeborahK

Comment: can you do `this._studyProvider.getStudyfromAPI(studyName).do(console.log)` does that print the new study?

Comment: The .do in my service does show my the .json in the console is that what you want to say ? @AhmedMusallam

Comment: yeah. so the new returned `Study` does it have a different `name`? I assume you are 100% sure the local variable `study` is changed to the newly returned study from JSON. it's strange to me that it is not reflected on the view. Do you see console errors ?

Comment: In fact it seem really strange to me. Because I added a 'console.log(study)' at the end of my fonction getstudy and here is the result after 2 calls of 'getstudy' and [here](https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/231885Capturedecran20170503a004518.png) is what is shows in the console @AhmedMusallam

Comment: so ` getStudyfromAPI` returns an array NOT an object. you'll have to adjust your getStudy to be:  `this._studyProvider.getStudyfromAPI(studyName)
     .subscribe( res => this.study=res[0],
                 err => console.error(err.status));` note the `res[0]` here to get the first element in the array. Alternatively make sure your endpoint returns a JSON object not array.

Comment: Whoooo I feel sooo stupid now ahah thanks a lot @AhmedMusallam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getStudyfromApi method was returning an array.
So i just have to change this in study.component

```
 this._studyProvider.getStudyfromAPI(studyName)
     .subscribe( res => this.study=res,
                 err => console.error(err.status));
```

by

```
this._studyProvider.getStudyfromAPI(studyName)
     .subscribe( res => this.study=res[0],
                 err => console.error(err.status));
```

and everything worked fine
Thanks @AhmedMusallam for the answer